# GoormIDE as 0.0.0.0?

Tags: neo4j

I am beginning to look into neo4j right now, so I installed it on goormIDE, inside an express templated container. (https://ide.goorm.io/)

I had to install java, configure it, etc. and I had to install neo4j. 
When I'm now running `service neo4j status`I get the message that it's running. 
Whenever, I attempt to go to the browser test-domain.goorm:7474, I get connection refused.

How do I set goorm up to listen to 0.0.0.0, thus allowing me to check for the neo4j browser that is supposedly listening on localhost:7474 after a successful installation?

Answer (score 0):

In the neo4j.conf (/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf),

you can set the listen address to 0.0.0.0

(uncomment that line).